# How can I speed up transcription availability for Zoom calls?

Tags: zoom-sdk

I'm building a Zoom integration with the Zoom API.

After a call, I would like to access the call transcript within 5 minutes. However, Zoom API only provides this later. I often experience 15-60 minutes delays.

How could I get the call transcript faster at a reasonable cost?

Options I have considered:

1. Don't build for Zoom

   - But my target users are here
2. Send bots to meetings

   - But it's costly and having a bot in a meeting can be a bad experience
3. Get people to use Zoom in their browser and capture captions from there

   - But requires a significant user behavior change
4. Build Mac and Windows apps that use Zoom local recordings and captions

   - But increases build complexity significantly
5. Wait until Zoom speeds up the availability of their transcript after a call

   - But they might do this only after several years
6. Educate users that waiting for 15-60 minutes is OK

   - But they will likely not agree
7. Use a 3rd party transcription service

   - But this gets expensive